# Form with checkboxs to input field and vice versa - missing first value

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms, checkbox

I have a small form, where I list an array `$menu` as checkboxes.

Using jQuery (see script below) I then put the values of the checkboxes into an ( eventually hidden ) input field. I know this is not traditional way , But I want to store them all as a single united value.

When loading the form again (or after submitting) I of course need to populate those fields again with the value that was stored as a string ( from the input field ).

I use a simple `strpos()` with a ternary operator for `"checked"`.

My problem is that on every load , the FIRST value that is checked on the list , will NOT be confirmed and will not be checked . Always the `first one` and `only the first one` (which is upper in the list - and I do not mean the `ABSOLUTE` first, but the first one to be previously checked . the first in the saved string.). Meaning that If I show the input field ( not hidden ), I can see the value in the string , but the checkbox is not `"checked"`.

all the rest is working well....

Maybe only my eyes are tired , but I can really not find where the problem is :-)

Any input will be greatly appreciated ..

```
global $menu;
    $output = '';

    for ($i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++){
        if ($menu[$i][2]){

        $find = $menu[$i][2];
        $pos = strpos($opp_array['brsa_menu_list'], $find);

            $output .=  '</br><input class="checkbox remove_check" type="checkbox" ' .(($pos) ? ' checked ':'') . 'name="option1" value="'  . $menu[$i][2] .'"> '  . $menu[$i][2] ;
        }
     }
echo '<b>Available menus  :  </b><br>' . $output .'<br>';

?>

<p>
    <input class="regular-text" id="sbrsamenu_list" name="brsa_s[brsa_menu_list]" type="text" value="<?php echo $opp_array['brsa_menu_list']; ?>"/>

    <label class="description" for="sbrsamenu_list">
    </br><?php echo 'Please write the menu items'; ?>
    </label>
</p>
```

and the js

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    // <![CDATA[
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    var $checkboxes = jQuery(".remove_check");
    $checkboxes.on('change', function() {
        var ids = $checkboxes.filter(':checked').map(function() {
            return this.value;
        }).get().join(' | ');
        jQuery('#sbrsamenu_list').val(ids);
    });


        });

    // ]]>
</script>
```

Comment: i didnt bother to study the question in detail (sorry), but try changing `for ($i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++)` to `for ($i = 0; $i <= 100; $i++)`. it might help

Comment: @Kuro - It does not .. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `$pos` is meant to be a boolean value, indicating whether a string appears in another, you should compare the value from `strpos()` against `false`:

```
$pos = strpos($opp_array['brsa_menu_list'], $find) !== false;
```

Otherwise, if `$find` appears at the start of your string, `strpos()` returns `0` which in your code would be equivalent to `false`.

Comment: Dear god. it works now. But I am utterly confused . why did this effect only the `FIRST` checked value, while working ok for all the rest ? I have maybe 25 values there , and I have tried every possible combination, and they all worked with the exception of always skipping the first one . If the implementation of `strpos()` was wrong, shouldn´t it fail for all ?? ( i am also not familiar with the syntax that you have posted - I´ll try to research now :-) ...

Comment: @ObmerkKronen If a match is found anywhere besides the first character of the searched string it will work as expected; this is just how `strpos()` is designed to work; if the string doesn't appear, it returns `false`.

Comment: ok, thanks, so just for tha sake of understanding better - that means that if i will add another delimiter pipe ( `|` ) in the beginning of the string as first character , then my original code will be valid ?